# How to search for all sub-tags of a specific tag with Evernote?

Tags: windows, macos, evernote

This question applies to the Desktop versions of Evernote (for PC and Mac).

Say you have the following tags

```
Work
->Job 1
->Job 2
```

Since job1 and job2 are subtags of Work their items are only tagged with job1 and job2. Is there a way to just click on Work and send see all the items in job1 and job2 - without having add the Work tag to all items in job1 and job2. Or even less ideal how to select multiple tags to search for at once (can't figure this one out on the Mac version of evernote.)

If there is NOT a way to do that is there a way to add a tag to a bunch of tags at once (so I can quickly add job1 and job2 tagged notes to also be tagged for work) - better still some kind of macro to automatically do that when ever I add job1 or job2 notes (similar to filtering email)?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible, tags seem to be separate.

You can however select multiple tags on the left by pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd> while selecting tags, viewing all items with any of these tags.

---

To mass-tag items, just select, drag & drop them onto the tag on the left. The items will get tagged with the tag you dropped them on.

Comment: cool, thanks, that works (I'm used to Windows/Ubuntu so I kept trying to press control instead of cmd... :) )

Answer (score 1):

There is a way now.

You can multi-select tags in the left column (using regular Shift or Ctrl methods).

Then in the main window filter, change All to Any:
"Viewing __ notes from All Notebooks matching Any of the following"

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility could be to write a post processing script that adds the upper tag on notes with the lower tag.

Answer (score 0):

The Evernote desktop client for Windows actually enables this now.

[image]

All the tags under "Computer Science" got selected by just clicking "Computer Science". The notebook listing panel then shows search results for all of the selected tags:

[image]

I'm using Evernote 6.0.6.1769 on Windows 7 64-bit.